# How to use Ethernet interrupt with vdx-6354 (vortex86dx)

Tags: x86, dos, turbo-c

I am new to vdx-6354 (PC/104) and I am getting familiar with it @ my work. 
We need to send/receive data over  Ethernet. I have managed to run DSOCKS library demo projects successfully but there is a problem. Our current project consists of  notable amount of codes and it's not possible to service receive requests in our main loop. We need to service the incoming tcp requests separately and somehow in an interrupt routine. Datasheet says that the interrupt vector is 0x62 on IRQ6. Can any one help me write the interrupt routine for this task?